# Using annotate for shapes and text in proc gmap

Tags: sas, choropleth

I am making a map using PROC GMAP that is choropleth showing an aggregate stat on the number of people in an FSA (3 character prefix of the postal code, so a geographic region that contains many postal codes).  I wish to label the centre of these FSA regions on the map with the FSA string and also have dots for specific set of postal codes (between 1 and 3 postal codes per FSA will be marked).

I am able to make my heatmap with the FSA strings labelled at centroid of the FSA, using the maplabel macro, however I have spent almost 3 days trying to get the dots.  I have come close where every dot appeared with the FSA string labelling that dot, however this is not what I need, and also the font of the FSA string was illegibly stretched and too small (increasing SIZE just stretched it further horizontally).

I have:

```
proc gmap map=mapt data =datat all;
id fsa;
choro decileByFSA /discrete COUTLINE=white legend=legend1 anno=annot;
format decileByFSA decileFormat.;
run;
quit;
```

I ran the maplabel macro to get labels for the FSA strings, which worked as expected.  I tried adding observations, one each for the dots I wanted to appear, but with:

```
function='pie'; style='psolid'; rotate=360; size=0.4; text='';
```

which was not successful (I tried many other variations).  On every attempt, either only one or the other of the annotation types would appear or, as I said above, the fsa text appeared too many times, skewed and in incorrect location.

From the documentation, I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you use SGPLOT instead? What version of SAS are you on?

Comment: Please show the annotation data.  Better yet try to reconstruct the issue with sample map and annotate data that is added to the question.  I would look at XSYS, YSYS and HSYS first

Comment: @Richard my annotate data, one for each of the text and dot type is as follows: